# MEF - Migration from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0

Tags: mef

I've got an easy sample from the internet that works fine in the .NET 3.5 framework using System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll version **v2.0.50727**

I've changed the project definition and changed the target to .NET 4.0 and it works perfect.

When I replace the v2.0.50727 version of the above .dll to the latest version which is **v4.0.30319** I get an error that complains during the composition of the container. The code where it break is as follows:

```
        private void LoadPlugins() {
            var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
                        container.ExportsChanging += new EventHandler(container_ExportsChanging);

            var batch = new CompositionBatch();
            batch.AddPart(this);
            container.Compose(batch); // throws Exception
        }
```

And the exception is the following:

```
System.ComponentModel.Composition.ChangeRejectedException was unhandled
Message=The composition remains unchanged. The changes were rejected because of the following error(s): The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.

1) More than one export was found that matches the constraint '((exportDefinition.ContractName == "MefTutorial.IPlugin") AndAlso (exportDefinition.Metadata.ContainsKey("ExportTypeIdentity") AndAlso "MefTutorial.IPlugin".Equals(exportDefinition.Metadata.get_Item("ExportTypeIdentity"))))'.

Resulting in: Cannot set import 'MefTutorial.PluginConsumer._myPlugins (ContractName="MefTutorial.IPlugin")' on part 'MefTutorial.PluginConsumer'.
Element: MefTutorial.PluginConsumer._myPlugins (ContractName="MefTutorial.IPlugin") --> MefTutorial.PluginConsumer
```

What do I need to do to migrate to the .NET 4.0 concerning **MEF**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the problem. Apparently in the previous version the notation was as mentioned in my previous comment, but in the new .NET 4.0 version the syntax for import should be:

```
code>
[ImportMany(typeof(IPlugin))] 
internal List _myPlugins { get; set; }
```

Notice the use of **List** and **ImportMany** instead of IList and Import.

Comment: Can't you use `IEnumerable<IPlugin>` and `ImportMany` on that? Works for me at least, and has the advantage of being strongly typed.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that another project still references the .net 3.5 version? The error message says that there are two exports of type `IPlugin`, which I'm quite certain of means that finds both the 3.5 and 4.0 version of the dll.

Check that only the 4.0 version of `MefTutorial` is referenced and/or present.

Comment: I'll second this. Visual Studio's 'Clean' is rubbish. It had me chasing a similar error the other day. It was only when I checked the output folder that I realised it was still full of old files...

Comment: yup, I had that problem as well, with MEF also. It still found old dlls and complained.

Comment: I even tried to start a new Simple project where I use the similar code. It appears that the same code is not compatible with the new version of dll.
The error message is indicating that 'more than one export was found' and that is exactly what I am trying to achieve. But why he thinks that my notation is as if I am importing one single instance!?

Comment: The consumer looks like this : 
 [Import(typeof(IPlugin))]
        internal IList<IPlugin> _myPlugins { get; set; }

Comment: OK, I found the problem. Apparently in the previous version the notation was as mentioned in my previous comment, but in the new .NET 4.0 version the syntax for import should be:  [ImportMany(typeof(IPlugin))] internal List<IPlugin> _myPlugins { get; set; }